# Including two category slugs in entries’ URLs

Tags: entries, categories, url

I have a section with two Categories fields, and I would like the entries’ URLs to include the slugs of the categories selected in each of those fields.

The Category Groups are:

- mySection

  - Employees
  - Employers
  - Executives
- myCategory

  - Vitality
  - Health
  - Safety
  - Career

So an entry that has “Employees” selected in the first Categories field, ad “Health” selected in the second Categories field should end up with the URL:

```
mywebsite.nl/employees/health/entrypage
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your section’s Entry URL Format to this:

```
{mySection.first.slug}/{myCategory.first.slug}/{slug}
```

`mySection.first` and `myCategory.first` will give you the first-selected category within those respective fields. Adding `.slug` after that will give you the slug of those categories.

If either of those category groups can have nested categories, you may want to change `.first` to `.last`, so the last-selected category’s slug makes it into the URL rather than the first one.

**Category URLs**

If you would like to make category URLs like this:

```
mywebsite.nl/employees/health
```

you will need to create a new Route in Settings → Routes, with the following URL pattern:

[image]

and point the route to whatever template you want to load when these URLs are matched.

Then from your template, you can fetch the actual category models like this:

```
{% set mySection = craft.categories({
    group: 'mySection',
    slug: matches[1]
}).first() %}

{% set myCategory = craft.categories({
    group: 'myCategory',
    slug: matches[2]
}).first() %}

{# Make sure the URL contained valid slugs #}
{% if not mySection or not myCategory) %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

From there you can do whatever you want with them. For example, you can display every entry that is related to both of them:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: ['and', {targetElement: mySection}, {targetElement: myCategory}]
}) %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

You can repeat all of those steps to do a similar thing for URLs that just have one category in them as well (just omit the second route token, and ignore all the `myCategory` stuff in the example code).

Comment: Thanks Brandon,

But how do I set the URL format of myCategory when I want it to be a child of mySection?

Comment: @MartijnLaFeber I'm not sure I'm following. I made some edits to your question based on what I thought you meant. Can you review that and make sure I'm understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Your edits are ok, thanks for that. But I would like to know if it is possible to navigate via category urls also?
What do I have to fill in for the Category URL Formats?

`{mySection.first.slug}/{myCategory.first.slug}`

Comment: @MartijnLaFeber Just updated my answer with details on that.